# Anypoint Platform Apps/Schedulers

Tags: api, mule, stimulsoft, cloudhub, anypoint-platform

Is there a way to get details of all the apps in an Anypoint Platform Business Group. For example, if there are 3 apps available in the RunTime Manager, I am looking at details like below:

[image]

I know there are cloudhub APIs which can get the details, but is there a custom API? If yes, can it be integrated with a reporting tool like PowerBI to create a live dashboard?

Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean by a custom API?

Comment: By custom API, I mean something which can give us the details above (in a JSON format probably) including that of schedulers.

Comment: Usually a custom API describes something that you develop and implement.

Answer (score 0):

All or nearly all REST APIs provided by Anypoint Platform return JSON, including the CloudHub REST API. You can check the platform APIs in [MuleSoft Dev Portal](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/).

You can use the `cloudhub/api/v2/applications/{domain}` endpoint to get details of an application: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/cloudhub-api/minor/1.0/console/method/%231839/

To get the schedulers information the endpoint there is a `cloudhub/api/applications/{domain}/schedules` endpoint: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/cloudhub-api/minor/1.0/console/method/%233128/

Both return JSON responses with the information described in above links.

I don't know if that is useful for PowerBI. If not, you can develop your own custom application to query above information and return it in a suitable format. Your application can implement an API of your design if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the details. What does {domain} indicate here?

Comment: It is the application name. You can see examples of using the API in Help Center. For example: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-update-the-loggers-in-Cloudhub-using-the-API. You need to obtain a bearer token first: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-generate-your-Authorization-Bearer-token-for-Anypoint-Platform